# php iconv on OSX with diacritics go wrong

Tags: php, macos, utf-8, ascii, iconv

i'm starting to get crazy:
this code on OSX 
    `echo iconv("UTF-8", "ascii//TRANSLIT", "groöt") . "\n";`

produces `gro"ot`  on OSX  but it produces `groot` on other Linux systems.

How is this possible, and how to change this?

I've tried it in php 5.4 and php 5.5, both give same results.